# sql running in Access 2010 but not sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Hi the code below works in access (part of line 24 was added for sql server = [Old_DB].[dbo].) but not in Sql Server 2012
The error says Invalid column name 'E.Analysisstatus' which is line 16. 
What what could cause this to not run in Sql Server.
Thanks

```
SELECT 
P.Semester, P.StudentID, P.Sessions, G.WithNewAnalysis AS RegWithNewAnalysis
FROM 
(SELECT 
StudentID, Semester, Count(*) AS Sessions
FROM 
Stats
WHERE 
DateofSession IS not Null
GROUP BY 
StudentID, Semester 
)  AS P 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
E.StudentID, E.Semester, Count(E.StudentID) AS WithAnalysis, 
Sum(IIf([E.Analysisstatus] =1,1,0)) AS WithNewAnalysis    /* line 16*/
FROM
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT Stats.StudentID, Stats.Semester, Stats.SessionNumber, Analysis.Analysisstatus
FROM 
Stats 
INNER JOIN 
[Old_DB].[dbo].[Analysis] ON Stats.StatsRefNo = Analysis.StatsRefNo  /* line 24*/
)  AS E
GROUP BY 
E.StudentID, E.Semester
)  AS G ON (G.StudentID=P.StudentID) AND (G.Semester=P.Semester);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets. i.e.

```
Sum(IIf(E.Analysisstatus =1,1,0)) AS WithNewAnalysis
```

instead of

```
Sum(IIf([E.Analysisstatus] =1,1,0)) AS WithNewAnalysis
```

I think E.[Analyststatus] or [E].[Analyststatus] will be valid but in this case the system is assuming [E.Analyststatus] is the fieldname which is not correct.

Comment: Hi Swagata you were correct in your assumption about the square brackets.

Comment: @maggs: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Square Brackets , 
Square Brackets are use to make SQL Data Engine know that the name of any object with space is a single name 
like if i want to pass a table name as Employee Details 
if i pass it separately , both word will be read as separate entity and so it will prompt an error if u pass it in [Employee Details] this will read as one word and it will accepted by SQL

in your case 
E.ANalusisstatus , here SQL is reading this as a single name and not with Alias which u have provided so do separate it

Thank You